Portfolio optimization with Scipy results in implausibly low risk score
I am using the following python code to answer the following question: What are the optimal portfolio weight choices to optimize returns for a given amount of risk, given a set of stocks and an index?
Specifically, I have 4 assets to build the efficient frontier.

Three stocks. In my portfolio, I can only take long positions in the stock.
One of them is the s&p500 ETF. I can take a long position in this, or take a short position with up to 200% leverage.

When I plot the efficient frontier I have this outcome:
.
Can someone tell me what I am missing?
Previously, I had already calculated the variance-covariance matrix and the assets' statistics that I do not report here for the sake of simplicity.
#GENERATING RANDOM WEIGHTS FOR QUESTION 2
np.random.seed(42)

num_portfolios = 10000
weights = np.zeros((num_portfolios, 4))

for i in range(num_portfolios):
    # Step 1: Generate initial random weights for the first three stocks
    w = np.random.random(3)
    w = w / w.sum() * 2  # Normalize these weights to sum to a value between 0 and 2

    # Step 2: Weight for the S&P500 ETF can be between -1 and 1
    w_spx = np.random.uniform(-1, 1)
    
    # Step 3: Combine weights and adjust to ensure they sum to 1
    total_investment = w.sum()
    total = total_investment + w_spx  # This can range from 1 to 3
    weights[i, :3] = w / total  # Scale down the weights for the first three stocks
    weights[i, 3] = w_spx / total  # Adjust the S&P500 ETF weight to maintain the sum of 1

# Check that the weights sum to 1 and the S&P500 weight is at maximum -1
assert np.allclose(weights.sum(axis=1), 1) and (weights[:, 3] >= -1).all()
# Portfolios returns
portfolio_returns2 = np.dot(weights, annual_returns)

# Portfolios volatility
portfolio_volatilities2 = np.sqrt(np.diag(np.dot(weights, np.dot(cov_mat, weights.T))))
portfolio_var2 = np.diag(np.dot(weights, np.dot(cov_mat, weights.T)))
portfolios_2 = pd.DataFrame({'ret':portfolio_returns2, 'risk':portfolio_var2})
weights = pd.DataFrame(weights)
weights.columns = ['w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w4']
portfolios_q2 = portfolios_2.join(weights)

portfolios_q2.head()
#Again, to find the efficient frontier, we generate the "grids" over portfolio returns
#we want to calculate the minimum variance for all the point on the grids of portfolio returns

min_var_ret2 = portfolios_2.ret.iloc[portfolios_2.risk.idxmin()] 

eff_ret2 = np.arange(min_var_ret2, portfolios_2.ret.max(), 
                  (portfolios_2.ret.max()-min_var_ret2)/100)
eff_risk2 = np.zeros(len(eff_ret2))


#then we can use the minimize function over each point on "eff_risk":
f = lambda x: x@cov_mat@x.T
x0 = np.array((0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)) #set the initial value of x, y, w, z

for ind in range(len(eff_ret2)):
    
    #set the optimization problem constraints:
    cons = ({'type':'eq','fun':lambda x:x[0] + x[1] + x[2] + x[3] - 1},  #constraint：x+y+z+w = 1
        {'type':'eq','fun':lambda x:x@asset_ret - eff_ret[ind]},  #constraint: set the return of the portfolio to be constant
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[0]},                        # Weights of first 3 stocks must be >= 0
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[1]},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[2]},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: 1 + x[3]},                    # Weight of S&P500 index can be down to -1
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: 2 - x[0] - x[1] - x[2]}       # Sum of weights of first 3 stocks <= 2
    )
    
#find the minimum variance of the portfolio given certain return level
    res = minimize(f, x0, constraints=cons)
    eff_risk2[ind] = res.fun
    #print(eff_y)

    
#now the eff_x and eff_y describe the risk and return combination on the efficient frontier.
#let's plot the efficient frontier:

plt.subplots(figsize=[10,10])
plt.xlabel('Risk', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Return', fontsize=16)
plt.scatter(portfolios_q2['risk'], portfolios_q2['ret'],marker='o', s=10, alpha=0.3)
plt.scatter(eff_risk2, eff_ret2, color='r', marker='x', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)

I tried to use the code I put in my question. I expected an output in line with financial theory, but the efficient frontier (red line) is not exactly following the upper bound of the efficient portfolios.

I just used it to underline what was more relevant in my question. If boring, I will remove it.

I see that you're constraining returns to be equal to your expected return with x@asset_ret - eff_ret[ind]. You should keep in mind that SLSQP doesn't always respect constraints if the constraint is unsatisfiable, or if minimization fails for some reason. Can you add assert np.isclose(res.x@asset_ret - eff_ret[ind], 0) after minimize() to check this possibility?

Checked, it does not generate any error, so the constraint is respected.

Thanks. Can you check that the value of res.success is true in every loop, as well? If not, does res.message give any insight?

I used the following code. Still no hint because the optimization runs smoothly.                                                                                                                               if not res.success:
print(f"Optimization failed at index {ind}")
print("Reason:", res.message)
assert np.isclose(res.x@asset_ret - eff_ret[ind], 0)

Nick, thank you for your time.  I managed to solve it. I would have another small question. I have two scenarios: one in which the risk-free asset is present and one in which is not. Optimal risky portfolio weights anyway should not change because in the scenario where the risk-free asset is not present, we are maximizing the return to volatility ratio. The portfolio with the highest return to volatility ratio will also be the one with the higher Sharpe ratio (we are just subtracting a constant from the numerator). Instead, I have small discrepancies. Is this due to Python numerical storage?

I don't have enough context to give a confident answer. I would need to see the code and the data being processed by that code. But what you've described doesn't sound like numerical instability. It wouldn't cause large errors.
